# Is there an additional block.json property to set to get an InnerBlocks child to respect the "supports" property?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

My InnerBlock child block doesn't seem to respect the [block.json "supports" property](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/) and I can't understand why not.

For reference, this custom block is comprised of:

- a parent `ucomm-blocks/accordion-block`
- a child `ucomm-blocks/accordion-block-item`

The relevant parts of their block.json files look like this...

**accordion-block.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "name": "ucomm-blocks/accordion-block",
  "title": "Accordion",
  "icon": "menu",
  "category": "ucomm-blocks",
  "allowedBlocks": [
    "ucomm-blocks/accordion-block-item"
  ],
  "attributes": {
    // non-relevant attributes
  }
}
```

**accordion-block-item.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "name": "ucomm-blocks/accordion-block-item",
  "title": "UConn Accordion Item",
  "icon": "menu",
  "category": "ucomm-blocks",
  "parent": [
    "ucomm-blocks/accordion-block"
  ],
  "allowedBlocks": [
    "core/columns",
    "core/cover",
    "core/embed",
    "core/group",
    "core/heading",
    "core/image",
    "core/list",
    "core/paragraph",
    "core/separator",
    "core/spacer"
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "backgroundColor": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "supports": {
    "anchor": true,
    "color": {
      "background": true,
      "text": true,
      "gradients": false,
      "link": false
    }
  }
}
```

When I add the `supports.color` property to the *parent*, the background/text color picker appears as expected for the parent. However, adding it to the child doesn't appear to do anything. The `allowedBlocks` of the accordion items all work correctly as well. No errors are thrown regarding the accordion block and I haven't found anything in the documentation that accounts for this. In all other respects these blocks work correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help you can provide.